# Sending Matplotlib figure through http request as numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have created a plot with Matplotlib, and save it into a variable with `f = plt.gcf()`. Now I could save it into a file, but instead I need to send it through an http response. How do I transform the variable `f` into a numpy array, so I can serialise it into the response, and how I would save the figure into a file on the other side? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the answer for anyone who finds this:
instead of doing `f = plt.gcf()`
do:

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
```